# Доступ к вектору структур внутри вектора структур

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Нужно получить доступ к вектору структур, которые вложены в другой вектор структур. Размеры обоих заранее известны и не будут изменяться, только данные внутри. Не привожу полностью структуры, чтобы не смущать головы лишними данными. Я представляю себе этот процесс так, но внутренний вектор не инициализируется.

```c
     //Header

    struct secondStruct
    { 
    // <немного других переменных тут>
    std::string secondText;
    }
    
    struct firstStruct
    {
    // <немного других переменных тут>
    std::string firstText;
    std::vector <secondStruct> SecondStruct;
    }
```

cpp:

```
//main.cpp
#include Header.h;

std::vector <firstStruct> FirstSTruct(10); // инициализируем верхний вектор, задаем конкретный размер.
std::vector <secondStruct> SecondStruct(5); // инициализируем внутренний вектор (??)

int main()
{

FirstSTruct[0].SecondStruct[0].secondText = "Some Text Here"; // ошибка доступа к вектору (выход за границы вектора)
}
```

чтяднт собственно?
По факту получается, что SecondStruct инициализируется как отдельный объект (к нему есть доступ):

```
SecondStruct[0].secondText = "Some Text Here"; // так все работает
```

Но как его инициализировать внутри FirstStruct ?

Comment: может ошибаюсь, но для инициализации полей структуры я обычно использую конструктор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector <secondStruct> SecondStruct(5); // инициализируем внутренний вектор (??)
```

Отнюдь. Это - глобальный вектор `SecondStruct`, и с внутренним он не имеет ничего общего, кроме типа и имени :)

```
struct firstStruct
{
// <немного других переменных тут>
std::string firstText;
std::vector <secondStruct> SecondStruct;
}
```

Чтобы инициализировать так, как вы хотите, надо дописать, например, так:

```
struct firstStruct
{
firstStruct():SecondStruct(5){}
// <немного других переменных тут>
std::string firstText;
std::vector <secondStruct> SecondStruct;
}
```

Ваш "работающий" код

```
SecondStruct[0].secondText = "Some Text Here"; // так все работает
```

работает, но только обращается к тому глобальному вектору `SecondStruct`, а не к `SecondStruct` внутри структуры.

Comment: Ларчик просто открывался, но такого вида решения я нигде не находил, везде варианты для двумерных векторов через:  vector<vector<T> > b(n, vector<T>())

Спасибо!!!

Comment: У вас не совсем двумерный вектор, а с "прослойкой" в виде структуры...

Comment: Да, потому я и встрял, и так вертел и сяк вертел. Ещё раз спасибо :)